# How to check an "empty" fill-in field which is not empty due to the format?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, is-empty

I have a window, containing some fill-in fields. One of them is meant to contain a date, having `99/99/9999` as a format. Due to that format, when emptying the field (selecting the content and press the <kbd>DEL</kbd> button), I see `"__/__/____"` on screen (the underscores mean spaces).

In order to check if this fill-in field is empty, currently the source code does this as follows:

```
IF Date_Fill-In:SCREEN-VALUE <> "/  /"
```

As you can see, this is heavily dependent on the format of the fill-in field.

Is there a built-in function I can use to check if the screen-value of a fill-in field is empty, without needing to check the format?

Thanks in advance
Dominique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the INPUT-VALUE property returning ?.

Comment: just for clarity, input-value is an attribute - https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/input-value-attribute.html

Comment: @StefanDrissen: Why do you make that remark? I'm using `Date_Fill-In:SCREEN-VALUE` and `Date_Fill-In:INPUT-VALUE` (mind the semicolons), not dots like in `Table1.Col1`.

Comment: So that you do not get confused looking for an input-value property since within the semantics of this question input-value is an /attribute/ (see the documentation url). 

A /property/ is something that you will find in a class (see ooabl stuff) with getters and setters.

Comment: Well ... those two terms are often used interexchangable. And since you cannot define properties for.widgets or attributes for classes there is also no risk of ambiguity.